# Links in html confused

Tags: html

I am making a web portal but I am a little confused with the use of the links. The problems is.

My application is in `http://localhost/applicacion/default.aspx`  (application is the application directory)

If i put a link `<a href="../Admin/defaultadmin.aspx">Link</a>` it takes me to

```
http://localhost/Admin/defaultadmin.aspx  instead of take me to ---> http://localhost/applicacion/Admin/defaultadmin.aspx
```

Then i try with Link it takes me to

```
http://localhost/applicacion/Admin/defaultadmin.aspx but if i am in another part of the site like http://localhost/applicacion/sales/defaultsales.aspx it takes me to 
http://localhost/applicacion/sales/Admin/defaultadmin.aspx witchs is wrong !!
```

what's the rigth combination so the link takes me always to the same point, having in mind tha the application directory can change in the installation so that part has to be dynamic, I means I can not put in the link `<a href="Application/Admin/defaultadmin.aspx">Link</a>` because the user may install it in another web site.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

You are stating to goto the parent directory by `../`:

```
<a href="../Admin/defaultadmin.aspx">Link</a>
```

If you want to go to a sub-directory then omit the `../` and just use the name of the sub-directory followed by the desired page:

```
<a href="Admin/defaultadmin.aspx">Link</a>
```